# Correctly extracting strings from a sentence

Tags: asp.net, arrays, regex, string, str-replace

I've been working on this problem for a while now, and I hope I could get some resolution to this.

I have a sentence that contains key information that I would like extracted.

Once I extract these strings, I will save them as an array and then compare those strings to what exists in my db.

What I'm having issues is successfully extracting the strings.

For example, I have this sentence:

`These are a list of automobiles along with their production dates: AC 3000ME (1979-1984), AC Shelby-Cobra (1961-2004), AC Frua (1965-1973)`.

I would like to extract: `3000ME`, `Shelby-Cobra`, and `Frua`.

Here is the code below:

```
 public string CarModelMethod()
        {
            string sentence = "These are a list of automobiles along with their production dates: AC 3000ME (1979-1984), AC Shelby-Cobra (1961-2004), AC Frua (1965-1973)";
            string[] array = sentence.Split(',');
            CarModel carModel = new CarModel();
            foreach(var item in array)
            {
                var carDataSource = _context.CarTable.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.CarModelName, $"%{item}%")).Select(x => x.CarId);
                foreach(var id in carDataSource)
                {
                    carModel.CarId = id;
                    _context.CarModel.Add(carModel);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Here's the PHP regex which I assume would work in ASP: [`AC\s*(.+?)\s*\((?:\d{4}-\d{4})\)`](https://regex101.com/r/YMezLS/1/) and you can find the desired results in `$1`

Comment: Thank you @MonkeyZeus. I'll test it!

Comment: No problem, just make sure that you interpolate any escape characters properly for your environment.

Comment: Try `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\bAC\s+(.*?)\s+\(").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. I really have to learn regex. Isn't there anything easier? For example, if I only want `3000ME ` can't I do this => `fullSentence.Contains(word);`

Comment: @JennyFromtheBlock You should bear in mind that matching a string between two strings means you know what kind of chars you need to match between which two patterns. Just `.Matches(s, "word")` makes little sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\bAC\s+(.*?)\s+\(")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `AC` - an `AC` word
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (`.Groups[1].Value` will hold this submatch): any 0 or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbAC%5cs%2b%28.*%3f%29%5cs%2b%5c%28&i=These+are+a+list+of+automobiles+along+with+their+production+dates%3a+AC+3000ME+%281979-1984%29%2c+AC+Shelby-Cobra+%281961-2004%29%2c+AC+Frua+%281965-1973%29):

[image]

Comment: I want to thank you for taking the time to explain this.